# why the openCV face recognition not able to find the training sets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am using openCV to train the data sets for face recognition. I have 3 pictures for as my training sets. Everything in the code works fine until I execute the code to train.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\lbph_faces.cpp:359: error: (-210) Empty training data was given. You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function cv::face::LBPH::train
```

Point to be noted that the path mentioned in the error doesn't even exist on my machine.

I have two python files, one is created to just see a persons face on webcam and save it on some location. Below is the code:-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print(x, y, w, h)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        img_item = "amitesh2.png"

        color = (255, 0, 0)
        stroke = 2
        width = x+w
        height = y+h
        rect = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(width, height), color, stroke)

        cv2.imwrite(img_item, roi_gray)
    cv2.imshow('test', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code is working as per the requirement. The problem is with the below code that is training and recognizing the face.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle
from PIL import Image

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
print(face_cascade)

recog = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
img_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images")

curr_id = 0
label_ids = {}
x_train = []
y_label = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img_dir):
    for fil in files:
        if fil.endswith("png") or fil.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, fil)
            label = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(root)).lower()
            #print(label, path)

            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = curr_id
                curr_id += 1
            id_ = label_ids[label]
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L")
            img_array = np.array(pil_image, "uint8")
            #print(img_array)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                roi = img_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_label.append(id_)

with open("labels.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recog.train(x_train, np.array(y_label))
recog.save("trainer.yml")
```

I have searched the entire StackOverflow. I could see posts, but couldn't find anything on my issue. Please give me some pointers.

Comment: Did you try to debug? I mean : at what function call do you see the error? What are the arguments you pass to that function? Do they look valid in the debugger? etc...

Comment: "recog.train(x_train, np.array(y_label))", this is the step where the error occurs

Comment: Do you have access to a python debugger to see the value of arguments you pass to this function? Else, can you print them just before passing them to see they are what you expect?

Comment: I have used print statement just after the "pickle.dump", the output is an empty list.

Comment: It sounds like you found the reason for the error, then?